# How can I use from names in ActionMailer? [Rails 2.3.5]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I want to show a pretty name in the e-mail clients

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick!

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def welcome_email(user)
    recipients    user.email

    # PRETTY NAMES
    from          "Prettiest Pony <prettypony@imaginarium.tld>"

    subject       "Welcome to My Awesome Site"
    sent_on       Time.now
    body          {:user => user, :url => "http://example.com/login"}
  end
end
```

See [ActionMailer basics](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html) for more information

Comment: Thank you, macek, that was exactly my question. Anyhow... do you know since what Rails version this works?